# Como organizar valor inteiros aleatórios em ordem decrescente num array em Java?

Tags: java, classificação

Preciso organizar os valores que o array recebe aleatoriamente e deixa-los em ordem decrescente, mas sinceramente não sei como fazer isso, aí está meu código, eu não consegui organizar.

```
package gerarOrganizar;
import java.util.Random;
public class GerarOrganizar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        int[] array = new int[10];
        Random gerador=new Random();
        int[] arrayF= new int[10];
        int j = 0;


        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            array[i]=gerador.nextInt(25);
            if(array[i]==0)
                i--;
        }//for

        while(j<10){//meu problema começa daqui em diante
            for(j=0;j<10;j++){
                for(i=0;i<10;i++){
                    if(comp<array[i]){
                        comp=array[i];
                        arrayF[j]=array[i];
                    }//if

                }//segundo for
            }//primeiro for
        System.out.println(arrayF[j]);
        }//while    
    }//main
}//class
```

Comment: Você precisa implementar o algoritmo de ordenação você mesmo, ou pode usar um método de ordenação já pronto e disponível na JDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em java isso é muito mais simples do que o quê está tentando, existe o método `sort` da classe estática Arrays feito para isso. Veja o exemplo completo abaixo:

## Ordem Crescente

```
package meupacote;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
public class GerarOrganizar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[10];
        Random gerador=new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
             array[i]=gerador.nextInt(25);
        }
        //Imprime o Array original
        System.out.println("Antes");
        for(int i: array){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        // Faz todo o trabalho para você 
        // e de forma mais eficiente do que a que estava tentando
        Arrays.sort(array);
        //Imprime o Array
        System.out.println("Depois");
        for(int i: array)
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Veja o exemplo rodando no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/VI90F2).

## Ordem Decrescente

Substitua

`int[] array = new int[10];` e  `Arrays.sort(array);`

por

`Integer[] array = new Integer[10];` e `Arrays.sort(array, Collections.reverseOrder());` respectivamente.

O motivo para tal substituição é que o [Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) só funcionará se argumento extender a classe objeto.